# Find and replace user names in a list of emails separates by special characters

Tags: sql, regex, t-sql, replace

I have a list of emails that are separated by different characters like , ; - /  etc. The goal is to replace only user names in those emails by xxx.

Ideally I should use TSQL to do it but I can use regex+Java if SQL is not able to do it.

Here is an example of input :

```
Alex.alex@cigroup.com;vito.maza@agen2.dom,vera@indus.ru;<vera@indus.it>; FRANCIS.TATA@RIZZ.COM-info@attl02.11.COM,mc.rap@wind.com/gorgo.ra13@lib.it;Lor Li Silvest [lor.Li.silvest@hotmail.it]
```

And here the output I need:

```
xxxx.xxxx@cigroup.com;xxxx.xxxx@agen2.dom,xxxx@indus.ru;<xxxx@indus.it>; xxxxxxx.xxxx@RIZZ.COM-xxxx@attl02.11.COM,xx.xxx@wind.com/xxxxx.xxxx@lib.it;xxx xx xxxxxxx [xxx.xx.xxxxxxx@hotmail.it]
```

Is there any ways to do it using sql query? If not, what is the regex expression to select all usernames at once?

Comment: Do you store your data as `;` separated items? It would cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: "Ideally I should use TSQL to do it" **That's just plain wrong.** Ideally, You will never have to deal with delimited strings in SQL. Ever.

Comment: Yes it can be a ; separated items, but it can be a , separated or - separated. Basically I was given a database were email is just a text field. Users were entering as many emails in it as they wanted with no restrictions at all.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, that's true. But I have some restrictions because legacy code was intended to do all string manipulations in plain sql.

Comment: What is your SQL-Server's version?

Comment: @Shnugo It's SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Your biggest issue will be the hyphen as delimiter, as this can occur within an email as part of the address too..

Answer (score 1):

This is an awful format. If there is any chance to change the input, this is your solution. If you have to deal with that crap (sometimes we have to take what we get from outside), you can start with something along this:

```
DECLARE @YourString NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'Alex.alex@cigroup.com;vito.maza@agen2.dom,vera@indus.ru;<vera@indus.it>; FRANCIS.TATA@RIZZ.COM-info@attl02.11.COM,mc.rap@wind.com/gorgo.ra13@lib.it;Lor Li Silvest [lor.Li.silvest@hotmail.it]';
```

--A mixture of string operations will transform your string to XML

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT('<mail><fragment>',REPLACE(REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@YourString,';','##delimit##'),',','##delimit##') AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),'@','</fragment><fragment>'),'##delimit##','</fragment></mail><mail><fragment>'),'</fragment></mail>') AS XML)
```

--this is the result

```
<mail>
  <fragment>Alex.alex</fragment>
  <fragment>cigroup.com</fragment>
</mail>
<mail>
  <fragment>vito.maza</fragment>
  <fragment>agen2.dom</fragment>
</mail>
<mail>
  <fragment>vera</fragment>
  <fragment>indus.ru</fragment>
</mail>
<mail>
  <fragment>&lt;vera</fragment>
  <fragment>indus.it&gt;</fragment>
</mail>
<mail>
  <fragment> FRANCIS.TATA</fragment>
  <fragment>RIZZ.COM-info</fragment>
  <fragment>attl02.11.COM</fragment>
</mail>
<mail>
  <fragment>mc.rap</fragment>
  <fragment>wind.com/gorgo.ra13</fragment>
  <fragment>lib.it</fragment>
</mail>
<mail>
  <fragment>Lor Li Silvest [lor.Li.silvest</fragment>
  <fragment>hotmail.it]</fragment>
</mail>
```

It is up to you (or some other masochistic SO-users :-) ) to proceed with this.

Happy Coding and Good Luck!